Filter rows in SQL query when a subquery returns null
I have a problem with subqueries. I'd like to select rows which contain a sum from a different table - so far no problem. However I'd like to filter for rows that don't have sum.
Example: Table1 has only an Id column, Table2 has an Id and a value column - all of datatype int.
Now I want to see all entries from Table1 and calculate the sum for that Id from Table2.
My query is very simple:
select 
    Id,
    (Select sum(Value) 
     from Table2 
     where Table1.Id = Table2.Id) as Total
from
    Table1;

However in Table2 there are only entries for Id = 1 and Id = 3. Since my query returns values for all three rows (showing NULL for Id = 2), I'd like to suppress the row for Id = 2.
I tried
select 
    Id,
    (select sum(Value) 
     from Table2 
     where Table1.Id = Table2.Id) as Total
from
    Table1
where 
    not (Total is null);

Unfortunately this is not allowed in SQL since I cannot access the value for Total.
What would be the best and easiest way to achieve this?

Please ask 1 specific researched non-duplicate question. Either ask re 1 bad query/function with obligatory [mre], including why you think it should return something else or are unsure at the 1st subexpression where you don't get what you expect or are stuck, justified by reference to authoritative documentation, or ask about your overall goal giving working parts you can do with justification & a [mre]--then misunderstood code doesn't belong. But please ask about unexpected behaviour 1st because misconceptions get in the way of your goal. [ask] [Help] Basic questions are faqs

A [mre] includes: cut & paste & runnable code including initialization; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. For SQL include DDL & tabular initialization code. For debug that includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) PS Invalid code does not mean anything so it does not communicate the doing of what one wished it did. PS "best" and "easiest" don't mean anything in particular.

You can only use/reference a 'calculated' column in the 'order by'.
Here are two options:
-- Option 1: Add the calculation in the WHERE clause
select 
[Id], 
(select sum([value]) from Table2 where Table1.[Id] = Table2.[Id]) as Total 
from 
Table1 
where 
(select sum([value]) from Table2 where Table1.[Id] = Table2.[Id]) is not NULL;

-- Option 2: Make the orginal query a subquery
select [Id], [Total] from 
(
select 
[Id], 
(select sum([value]) from Table2 where Table1.[Id] = Table2.[Id]) as Total 
from 
Table1 
) subquery where [Total] is not NULL;


You don't need subqueries. You can do:
select a.id, sum(b.value) as total
from table1 a
join table2 b on b.id = a.id
group by a.id

If there are actual nulls in table2 then you can enclose your query as a table expression:
select *
from (
  select id,
    (select sum(value) from table2 b where b.id = a.id) as total
  from table1 a
) x
where total is not null

total is actually available in the outer scope.

thanks a lot for your suggestion - I did not publish the original query but a very simplified version of it because of the complexity. Unfortunately my query is much more complex than what I posted - it contains two calculated values and each of them has already a lot of conditions - that would make the query too complicated and unreadable for me.
I had already thought of using a join but that would complicate the query too much

You can use a Common Table Expression to resolve it
WITH CTE_X AS(
 select 
    Id,
    (Select sum(Value) 
     from Table2 
     where Table1.Id = Table2.Id) as Total
from
    Table1)
    SELECT *
    FROM CTE_X
    WHERE Total IS N

